# Rotate QPixmap around an arbitrary point

Tags: c++, image, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to do a thing where I rotate an image around an arbitrary point (generally within the bounds of the image itself), but I want to retain the point that corresponds to the untransformed image's origin.

Thus far, I'm using the QTransform approach to rotate the image:

Qt Code:

```
image.transformed(QTransform()
                          .translate(-point.x(), -point.y())
                          .rotateRadians(rot)
                          .translate(point.x(), point.y()));
```

This returns an image that is "rotated" around the point, but it is drawn into a new image object whose origin is respective to the transformed image, not the original, so painting the image makes it have the correct angle but is translated somewhere way out of position. Is there a way to either A] calculate the original origin's location in the transformed image, or B] rotate an image without altering its origin?

Here's the program in practice:

Without any rotation:

[image: Without Rotation]

With rotation (the image is drawn with the top left corner of the new box being the origin, rather than the image's pre-transformed origin):

[image: With Rotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the solution that I came up with is that, in order to find the offset from the original image and the rotated image, I find the center points of both images and calculate that offset, then use that with the rotated point as the location to draw my image when painting.

```
QPixmap ImageBone::getTransformedImage(QPointF point, qreal rot, QPointF &origin, QPointF anchor = QPointF(0, 0))
{
    QPointF center = QPointF(image.width() / 2, image.height() / 2);
    qreal dist = QLineF(anchor, center).length();
    qreal a = qAtan2(anchor.y() - center.y(), anchor.x() - center.x());
    QPointF rotAnchor(qCos(rot + a) * dist, qSin(rot + a) * dist);
    rotAnchor += center;

    QPixmap rotImage = image.transformed(QTransform()
                                  .translate(-point.x(), -point.y())
                                  .rotateRadians(rot)
                                  .translate(point.x(), point.y())
                                 );

    QPointF rotCenter = QPointF(rotImage.width() / 2, rotImage.height() / 2);
    QPointF offset = rotCenter - center;

    origin = point - (rotAnchor + offset);

    return rotImage;
}
```